# Prove that the product of some numbers between perfect squares is $2k^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, products

Here's a question I've recently come up with:

> Prove that for every natural $x$, we can find arbitrary number of integers in the interval
>   $[x^2,(x+1)^2]$ so that their product is in the form of $2k^2$.

I've tried several methods on proving this, but non of them actually worked. I know, for example, that the prime numbers shouldn't be in the product.
 I was also looking for numbers $x$ so that between $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$ there is actually the number $2k^2$ for some natural $k$. If we find all of these numbers, then we should prove the case only for the numbers which are not in this form.
 These $x$s have this property: $x^2<2k^2<(x+1)^2$ leading to $x<k\sqrt 2<x+1$ and $x\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}<k<(x+1)\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$. This means there should be a natural number between $x\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ and $(x+1)\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$. 
I've checked some of the numbers that aren't like that with computer, and they were: $3,6,10,13,17,...$. the thing i noticed was that the difference between the two consecutive numbers of that form, is either $3$ or $4$. I think this has something to do with the binary representation of $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ but I don't know how to connect it with that. I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: Remark: The statment is false for $x=0$, since there are no natural numbers between $0^2$ and $(0+1)^2$

Comment: Good work. But I'm just wondering, have you invented this by yourself or have you found this problem somewhere?

Comment: No, i haven't invented this. A friend of mine told me he got it from his teacher. But we are not getting anywhere already.

Comment: @CODE Many (most?) consider $0$ a natural number. Better to say "positive" to avoid possible misunderstandings.

Comment: @CODE,"come up with" and "come across" a problem have different(entirely opposite) meanings.I tried using induction but haven't gotten anywhere.We may have to consider the prime factorization of k since there are never two nunbers k and 2k between two consecutive perfect squares,but I don't think that will get us anywhere.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, thanks for noting that. I guess the readers will get this anyway, by reading the comments!

Comment: @rah4927 That's a good observation. Please share it if you got anywhere with that :)

Comment: Isn't the statement false for $x = 1$?? The numbers between $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$ are $2$ and $3$..

Comment: @Ishfaaq Well, as $2$ can be represented as $2*1^2$ i don't think there is any problem!

Comment: Okay if there is no stipulation on $k$ and if it can be equal to $1$, then doesn't the problem reduce to finding an even number between $x^2$ and $(x +1)^2$?? Any even number, $y$ between $x^2$ and $(x +1)^2$ is representable in the form $2m * 1^2$ innit..

Comment: Right I think I got it.. $m$ has to be a perfect square..

Comment: @Ishfaaq Oh, i think you quite misunderstood the question. It should be as $2*k^2$(if we double a perfect square), not $2mk^2$.

Comment: If let's say $x^2=25$ and $(x+1)^2=36$ which numbers have product of the form $2k^2$?

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas $27\cdot28\cdot30\cdot35$ or $32$.

Comment: Oh so we may not choose only two numbers.now it seems interesting

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas 32 might be right for that case. Guys, i don't think this question has a counterexample. Please stop posting  things that you think isn't going to work! Instead, Helping us on proving it would be a good idea :P

Comment: I don't think there will be a nice pattern and the proof would be rather abstract. Solutions like $65\cdot66\cdot70\cdot77\cdot78$ for the case $x=8$ are hard to predict.

Comment: @barto Oh, did you find that solution with a computer? when i'm looking for solutions, i use the prime factorization anyway.

Comment: I'm doing all this by hand ;) I don't feel like writing a script for it. But $72$ is easier to find for $x=8$.

Comment: @barto, Oh, thanks for telling, i realized i had a mistake in writing the question. The numbers i found $3,6,10,13,17,...$ were the ones that there is no $2k^2$ between $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$. so we should only prove the case for these numbers, if we find out where do they come from.

Comment: I definitely remember reading this before, in a PDF related to some other question on this site. But which one ? I think (but I'm not sure) that it might have been the one about binomial coefficients which are also perfect powers.

Comment: @Lucian,does the paper have anything to do with Chebyshev's equation?

Comment: @rah4927: I don't think so.

Comment: @CODE Unless I missed something, the claim is false for $x=13$. You said you made a computer search for $x=13$, what solution  do you find in this case ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Which claim do you think is false for $x = 13$? [$171\cdot 180\cdot 190 = 2 \cdot 1710^2$, if it's that]

Comment: @DanielFischer I understand now, the claim was about a product of an ARBITRARY number of integers in a given interval, while I understood it as a product of just tow integers. My mistake.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I actually edited the body so that it would be clear for everyone this time, i hope.

Comment: @CODE I think the tail end of this question is only confusing/complicating things - yes, the cases where there exists a $k$ with $x^2\leq 2k^2\leq (x+1)^2$ are trivial, but it's not clear that a solution to the problem will have to break down into trivial and not.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Well i just thought like sharing what i had done, and that was it! No idea if it will come to any use or not.

Comment: This should answer your first question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624251/product-is-twice-a-square

Comment: @benh Thanks. That helped a lot actually, but i still wonder if there is a elementary proof for it.

Comment: The numbers where we can just use a single factor seem to form the Beatty sequence for sqrt 2 which seems quite reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer to point out that the question was answered in comments by benh: This question is a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624251); the latter question was answered by Gerry Meyerson who found a proof in [this paper](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/selfridge.pdf) of Granville and Selfridge.